# How can I change string to list in R?

Tags: r, shiny

can someone help me ? I need to change string to list. Everything works fine when the inside of the parentheses is not in quotes. However, in my RShiny application, I am forced to use a string in parentheses. **But the important thing is that it will not always be just YES and NO. There may be others depending on the dataset.**

**An example that works**

```
vl = list(Yes = 2, No = 2)

#Output of str(vl):

List of 2
 $ Yes: num 2
 $ No : num 2
```

**I need the same output for**

```
vl = ...("Yes = 2, No = 2")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `eval`/`parse` combination can be used to execute arbitrary strings as code, e.g.

```
v1 <- eval(parse(text=paste0("list(","Yes = 2, No = 2",")")))
v1
#$Yes
#[1] 2
#
#$No
#[1] 2

str(v1)
#List of 2
# $ Yes: num 2
# $ No : num 2
```